# yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00 date format in MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

How I can get current date on YYYY-MM-dd (2016-10-28) format in MDX?

```
Format(Now(),'YYYY-MM-dd')
```

Doesn't work.

EDIT:
I've just check that MDX convert my YYYY-MM-dd format to yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00 (I compare my date with current date) so I need something like:

```
Format(now(), "yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow... what else have you tried? A simple google search seems to produce your answers - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/84cdcfae-2304-4c55-b7e4-55753e5541ec/format-issue-in-mdx?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Comment: Please include the output that you get currently, within your question

Comment: @testtest11 - you need to include a script where this "Doesn't work" as the context of use is important with mdx - are you feeding this formatted date into a dynamic mdx script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never even heard of MDX but with a quick Google search it seems you should use the following format:

```
Format(Now(),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Notice the lower case `y` for year.

This information was deduced [from here.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fdee9f45-8383-4446-b022-e9e877477aec/mdx-date-format?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

**After Edit**

The new format you want would therefore be:

```
Format(Now(),'yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00')
```

Comment: @Testtest11: Well what doesn't work about it? What output are you getting?

Comment: why is this marked as answer and upvoted twice if it does not work!!! p.s. mdx is a multi-dimensional declarative language - sort of like sql but actually pretty

Comment: @whytheq: Well... only the OP can accept the answer, so perhaps it turns out that it does work... hard to tell when the OP isn't responding to anything...

Comment: Yes, I had problem with data comparison, not formatting.